# composer self-update triggers github deprecation notice for access token - where to apply changes?

Tags: github, composer-php

The deprecation notice email I get from github states *'your personal access token for Composer was used as part of a query parameter to access an endpoint through the GitHub API. Please use the Authorization HTTP header instead'*. They provide instructions, my problem is finding where I apply them. I remember when installing Composer, I had to set up the access token on github within command line, but have no idea where that info was stored?

Comment: Afraid not, my problem is where to make the changes - I'm not sure whether 'composer self-update' or 'composer update' (on a drupal install) triggered the notice, but in either case I don't know what file to make the changes in, there is no mention of github in the composer.json file for the drupal install

Comment: Then have a look at your "global" composer.json. For example, on my Ubuntu system, such data is stored in `~/.composer/auth.json`

Comment: Aha - thanks Nico, yes looks like that's the file, exactly the path you suggested - happy to accept as answer if you post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be multiple places to put such tokens. If you want it the easiest way, put the token directly in the `composer.json` of your project - but you should be aware of the consequences. Putting this file under version control would also put your private access token in that version control, and anyone who has read-access to that repository can also access your token.

The better approach: place such configuration in `~/.composer/` (or it's equivalent on Windows), the global composer directory of your system. In the file `auth.json`, you can put all kinds of tokens. And that's how this file could look like:

```yaml
{
    "bitbucket-oauth": {},
    "gitlab-oauth": {},
    "gitlab-token": {},
    "github-oauth": {
        "github.com": "your-token"
    },
    "http-basic": {
        "updates.ez.no": {
            "username": "abc",
            "password": "def"
        }
    }
}
```